# Laravel 5 migration create table, got error class 'illuminate\database\schema' not found

Tags: php, laravel-5

When I run `php artisan migrate`, I get the following error:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
>
> Class 'Illuminate\database\schema' not found

How can I solve this?

Comment: `illuminate\database\schema`? Should be `Illuminate\Database\Schema` and youll need that class as it is part of the framework and required for your migrations to work :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There no `Illuminate\Database\Schema`, you're most likely want to use `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema`.